# Something overrides Vuetify divider colors globally

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a weird problem that after updating Vuetify from 1.1.9 to 1.2.3 all my dividers are much darker than they were before and how they are in every example in their documentation.

This is how it has to be:

[image]

And this is mine(I think you can see the noticable difference.):

[image]

While inspecting, I was able to see that color of the class is correct:

```
.theme--light.v-divider {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
}
```

And something, exactly this overrides the background color to the same color it was for some reason:

```
.application .theme--light.v-navigation-drawer .v-divider, .application .theme--light.v-navigation-drawer:not(.v-navigation-drawer--floating) .v-navigation-drawer__border, .theme--light .v-navigation-drawer .v-divider, .theme--light .v-navigation-drawer:not(.v-navigation-drawer--floating) .v-navigation-drawer__border{background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.12));}
```

**Disabling both of them in Chrome's tools makes dividers right color.**

So the question is, why it is happening and what can I do to fix this? Any help is much appreciated.

**Edit:** I think it is not associated with the update because I rolled back to the earlier version to check if it is the issue, it was not.

Comment: Provide a [codepen(s?)](https://template.vuetifyjs.com/) if it's not a trouble. If it looks fine in docs then likely you've done something different, so provide more code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to add **!important** to your class and it will not be overwritten.

```
.theme--light.v-divider {
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.12) !important; 
}
```

Comment: This is not the best solution but the permissible

Comment: What worked is to set it to `transparent` instead of `rgba(0,0,0,0.12)`